# Validar tabla vacia

Tags: javascript, html, table

Necesito saber cuando mi tabla de html contiene o no datos.

Como primera vista, mi tabla no contiene dato alguno y se carga desde este div:

```
<div class="card-body">
       <div id="tabla">
           Sin datos disponibles
       </div>
</div>
```

Y por medio de una vista parcial, estoy cargando datos dentro de ese div que contiene la table,tr etc..

Pero lo unico que necesito es validar, cuando la tabla no contiene datos todavia, por medio de un boton

Comment: que es lo que has intentado?

Answer (score 1):

Puedes usar **firstChild** que devuelve **null** cuando el div selecionado no tiene un hijo para validar si tiene dicha tabla o no:

```
<body>
    <div class="card-body">
      <div id="tabla"></div>
    </div>

    <script>
      const tabla = document.getElementById("tabla");

      if (tabla.firstChild) {
        
        console.log('No tiene tabla');
      }else{
        console.log('Tiene tabla');
      }
    </script>
  </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Se me ocurre algo como esto

```js
//Creamos función para validar si tiene datos
function validarTabla(){
  //Obtenemos todos los tr de la tabla y los almacenamos en una variable tipo arreglo 
  var trs = document.querySelectorAll('#tabla table tr');
  //Almacenamos en variables los elementos leyenda y la tabla
  var leyenda = document.getElementById('leyenda');
  var tabla   = document.querySelector('#tabla table')
  
  //Si la cantidad de trs es mayor a 0 lo interpretará como verdadero
  if(trs.length){
    //Entonces ocultará la leyenda
    leyenda.style.display = 'none';
    //Y mostrará la tabla
    tabla.style.display = 'block';
  }else{
    // En caso de que la cantidad de tr sea 0 lo interpretará com falso
    // Y ocultará la tabla y mostrará la leyenda
    leyenda.style.display = 'block';
    tabla.style.display = 'none';
  }
  
}

//EJECUTAMOS FUNCIÓN
validarTabla();
```

```html
<div class="card-body">
    <div id="tabla">
     <!--Creamos una etiqueta P oculta-->
     <p style="display:none" id="leyenda">Sin Datos Disponibles</p>
     <table>
     <!--Descomenta este TR para ver el funcionamiento-->
     <!--
        <tr>
          <td>Hola Mundo</td>
        </tr>
      -->
     </table>
    </div>
</div>
```